# Set wrong GPS unit in degree and want to change to meter while editing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, gps

I want to edit the GPS result in ArcMap, but I found that there is a problem.
I set the wrong unit while I used the GPS outside , and the unit is "degree".
Although the coordinate system is correct, I still cannot change the unit to meter.

Is there any method that I can edit the unit to meter using ArcMap?

Answer (score 3):

If the values were actually stored in the range of -180 to 180 (longitude) or -90 to 90 (latitude), then you can't just edit the coordinate system, you'll need to [project](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000007m000000) to the correct one.

If on the other hand you just need to redefine the feature class's coordinate system, without changing the stored geometry, you can use the [Define Projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000) tool, or set the coordinate system in the [feature class properties](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002200000002000000.htm).